# save query data to array

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to retrieve all data from mysql database. I already try the query in phpmyadmin and it's work(return more than 1 row data). The problem is the query return more than one row data and I don't know how to save all data in the variable

This is the code :

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('
                            SELECT name 
                            FROM module m
                            WHERE module_id in (select module_id
                                               from role_crew_module
                                               where role_id = "' . $role_id . '"
                                              )');
                            $temp = $command->query();
                            $module = $temp->read()['name'];
```

when i echo the $module it's just show 1 data. How should i save all data into variabel ? maybe save to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 min research on Google and i found [THIS (it's a link)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbDataReader#readAll-detail)

Just use `$module = $temp->readAll();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do this:

```
$temp = $command->query();

while($row = $temp->read()['name']){
    $new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}
```

Comment: qkhfoimfhqsf i forgot the `;` after `$new_array[] = $row`